# Javascript setInterval() function not working in drawing to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a line in a canvas. I am trying to make the line moving with time. I am using the following code to do so

```
var ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
for (var x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
    setInterval(draw(x, 0, ctx), 3000);
    x = x++;
}
```

And here is the draw function

```
function draw(x, y, ctx) {
    ctx.moveTo(10 + x, 400);
    ctx.lineTo(11 + x, 400);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

But the setInterval() function is not working and the line is being drawn instantly. Its not waiting for 3s to proceed to next pixel.
Am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) needs a function as the first parameter. Right now you are just calling `draw(x,0,ctx)` and it returns `undefined`. So your code is equivalent to setTimeout(undefined, 3000).

Instead you need to provide a callable function and invoke `draw` from it. Try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    draw(x, 0, ctx);
}, 3000);
```

Another problem is due to typical closure in loop behavior. You will need to create separate scope to be able to work with individual values of `x`:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
    (function(x) {
        setInterval(function() {
            draw(x, 0, ctx);
        }, 3000 * x);
    })(x);
    x = x++;
}
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) question for more examples how to fix situations like this.

Comment: Not working yet. Does the for loop still continues even if the function inside setinterval is not called?

Comment: The updated code still have the same problem. Can you rather see it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Oh, you want it to draw one pixel in 3s. Check updated code with `3000 * x` interval.

Comment: Can you create a demo with the problem?

Comment: I have a button on an html page. If i click the button then it will draw a line like creating a road slowly.

Comment: Dude what spell checker you using? undefined !== undfined